# Symplectomorphisms of a Riemann surface

Tags: reference-request, riemann-surfaces, symplectic-geometry

Let $X$ be a compact Riemann surface (one dimensional complex manifold) of genus $g > 1$, fix a non-degenerate two form $\omega$ on $X$, it is automatically closed by dimension reasons, so it is a symplectic structure on $X$.

A symplectomorphisms of $(X,\omega)$ is a diffeomorphisms $g$ of $X$ preserving form $\omega$ i.e. $g^* \omega = \omega$.

What we can say about the group of all symplectomorphisms of $X$? Is it related to analytic automorphisms of $X$? Is it finite or infinite? What are orbits of the action on $X$? I don't know anything about this group, except the definition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can say an immense amount.

This is the simplest possible case of the groups $\text{Symp}(M)$, where $M$ is a symplectic manifold. First allow me to say some generalities on those.

---

If $M$ is a connected symplectic manifold, the group $\text{Symp}(M)$ acts transitively on ordered sequences $(x_1, \cdots, x_n) \in M^n$ so that all $x_i \neq x_j$ (unless $i = j$). This is called "$n$-transitivity", and should be read as saying "I can take any $n$ distinct points to any other $n$ distinct points". This is easily implied by the claim that the group $\text{Symp}_c(M)$ of *compactly supported* symplectomorphisms (those that are the identity outside of a compact set) acts transitively on $M$. I will leave this implication as an exercise to you, but explain why $\text{Symp}_c$ acts transitively.

This is best discussed by the construction of Hamiltonian vector fields. Given a function $f$ on a domain, one defines $X_f$ to be the unique vector field with $\omega(X_f, Y) = df(Y)$ for all vector fields $Y$. Then flow along $X_f$ preserves the symplectic form, and $\text{supp}(X_f) \subset \text{supp}(f)$. Now it suffices to show that the orbits of $\text{Symp}_c$ are open sets, as then we would have a decomposition of $M$ into disjoint open sets; thus orbits would be all of $M$. So we only need to construct a Hamiltonian vector field taking us to a nearby point.

So pick a standard symplectic chart around each $x \in M$; we will show that in $U \subset \Bbb R^{2m}$, there is a Hamiltonian vector field, compactly supported in $U$, flowing $0$ to any point sufficiently close to $0$.

To do this, if $v \in \Bbb R^{2m}$ is any vector, let $f_v(x) = \langle v, x\rangle$; because this is linear, we also have $df_v = \langle v, -\rangle$ at every point. Because the symplectic form here is $\omega(X_v, x) = \langle X_v, Jx\rangle = \langle -JX_v, x\rangle$, and by definition $\omega(X_v, x) = df_v(x) = \langle v, x\rangle$, we find that we must have $X_v = Jv$, where $J$ is the multiplication-by-$i$ map on $\Bbb R^{2m} = \Bbb C^m$.

In particular, $X_v$ is just "flow in the constant direction $Jv$". Replacing $f_v$ with $\beta f_v$, where $\beta$ is a bump function equal to $1$ near $0$ and supported inside a compact subset of $U$, we obtain a corresponding vector field $X'_v$ which is compactly supported inside $U$, but for small $t$ the time-$t$ flow just sends $0$ to $tJv$, and hence an orbit of $\text{Symp}_c(M)$ is open, as desired.

In particular, note that $\text{Symp}_c(M)$ must be infinite-dimensional, given that it has a surjective map to an open subset of $M^n$ for all $n$ (that is, $n$-transitivity means this group must be gigantic).

---

In dimension $n = 1$ (real dimension 2), however, things become much more simple: $\text{Symp}(M) = \text{Vol}(M)$, the group of diffeomorphisms fixing a particular volume form. This group similarly acts $n$-transitively in any dimension, and is in many ways much simpler than the symplectomorphism group. In fact, the original [Moser trick](https://www.math.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/~mabreu/GD/moser.pdf) proves a few facts: 1) any two volume forms $\omega_1, \omega_2$ of the same volume are related by some diffeomorphism $f$; and 2) the full group $\text{Diff}(M)$ is homotopy equivalent to the subgroup $\text{Vol}(M)$ of diffeomorphisms preserving a fixed volume form. So there is "no new topology to be had" in studying volume-preserving diffeomorphisms. This is very much not true in the symplectic case (in higher dimensions, of course).

None of these are related to analyticity (real or complex).

---

For lots of interesting facts about many related groups (Diff, Symp, Vol, ...) see Banyaga's [book on the subject](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780792344759). One famous fact: when $M$ is compact, the connected component of the identity $\text{Vol}_0(M)$ is a simple group. (In the symplectic case, one has to further restrict to the kernel of a certain map called the flux homomorphism; see Banyaga's book or the shorter [article by McDuff](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01388450.pdf).)

Comment: Nicely written :)